# Add ons for videogame development

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, rigging, add-on

I am currently building the assets for a video game using blender; however I will like to start implementing add-ons that would make the task of creating all the assets much faster and easier. 
In this case I really need for procedural generation, uv unwrapping, animation and texturing.
What are some of the best add-ons that can be implemented? both general and specific. User experience feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of question is too huge for a specific answer . . . My advice is: http://blenderartists.org/forum/ and http://polycount.com/categories helped me a lot, with Blender Stack Exchange, to understand whis world. Take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dark Blender is a modified Blender Build specifically for Game Asset Creation. You can find it's download link and BlenderArtists thread [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383624-Dark-Blender-(Official-Thread)-optimized-for-sculpting-and-game-asset-creation).